# can't find project folder after docker pull on AWS EC2

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, docker-compose, pull

```
[ec2-user@ip-... ~]$ sudo yum update -y
    // ok
[ec2-user@ip-... ~]$ sudo amazon-linux-extras install docker
    // ok
[ec2-user@ip-... ~]$ sudo service docker start
    // ok
[ec2-user@ip-... ~]$ sudo usermod -a -G docker ec2-user
    // ok
[ec2-user@ip-... ~]$ docker login
    // ok
[ec2-user@ip-... ~]$ mkdir myprojectfolder
    // ok
[ec2-user@ip-... ~]$ cd myprojectfolder
    // ok
[ec2-user@ip-... ~]$ docker pull myusername/myproject:latest
    // apparently ok (if I try doing it again it says that
    // the image is present and at the latest version)
[ec2-user@ip-... ~]$ docker-compose up
    // ERROR:
    //    Can't find a suitable configuration file in this directory or any
    //    parent. Are you in the right directory?

    //    Supported filenames: docker-compose.yml, docker-compose.yaml
```

The `myprojectfolder` folder seems to be empty even if the pull succeded. Maybe EC2 puts docker stuff in another predetermined folder? I can't go on with docker-compose if I don't cd into the folder.

**Where am I going wrong in starting my Docker project on AWS EC2?**

Comment: The `compose` command requires the `.yaml` file.  Did you want to do something like `docker run myusername/myproject:latest`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not downloading a folder, you are downloading a image, you can see with `docker images`. Try:

```
docker run -d --name myprojectName myusername/myproject:latest
```

This will start your docker. remember, you can use `-it` instead `-d` to use an interactive option.